# C# / JSON - Invoke a method with a List<object> as parameters

Tags: c#, arrays, json, reflection

I am having a lot of trouble on my code, I am trying to make some sort of parser. Basically I am trying to get data from a JSON file, and use that data to call methods from my code.

Here's a basic example of my JSON file

```
{ "story": { "Talk": [ "me", 1, 1 ] } }
```

Now I have a class called `DialogueSystem`, it contains a function called `Talk` with three parameters, string, int, int.

I am using `SimpleJSON` to get my JSON data, but I am guessing it's similar to other JSON parsers.

Also, I have other functions which have different parameters which is why I am forced to use reflection

Anyways, here's the code that gets the json data, and tries to use Reflection to call the Talk method.

```
// Gets the JSON and parses it
JSONNode Node = JSONNode.Parse(jsonFile());
var method = sys.GetType().GetMethod(""); // Reflection stuff

foreach (JSONNode item in Node["story"].Keys) // the Keys just gives me every key that's in the story node/key
{
    List<object> parameters = new List<object>(); // List containing the parameters, to be used when invoking the method

    for (int i = 0; i < Node["story"][item].Count; i++)
    {
        //This part tests if it's a string or int and adds it as such
        string data = Node["story"][item][i];
        int n;
        bool isNum = int.TryParse(data, out n);

        if (isNum)
        {
            parameters.Add(n);
        }
        else
        {
            parameters.Add(data);
        }
    }
    // Invoke the method using it's method name and the method parameters
    method.Invoke(item, parameters.ToArray());

}
```

Btw, my `Talk` class just prints a text based on the given input.

For some reason, I get this error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object Dialogue.StoryTeller.ReadStory (Dialogue.DialogueSystem sys)
>   (at Assets/Dialogue System/Scripts/StoryTeller.cs:57)

If you have any idea how to fix it, or maybe make it better, that would be awesome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after searching everywhere on the Microsoft docs and stack overflow, I found out that I needed to change two things.

First of all I had to change `var method = sys.GetType().GetMethod("");`
to this `var method = sys.GetType().GetMethod(item.ToString().Replace("\"", ""));`
(Which I also moved inside the for loop in order to use `item`)

Also, I needed to change the invoke `method.Invoke(item, parameters.ToArray());` to this `method.Invoke(sys, parameters.ToArray());`

So the whole code is now this

```
Node = JSONNode.Parse(jsonFile());

foreach (JSONNode item in Node["story"].Keys)
{
    List<object> parameters = new List<object>();
    var method = sys.GetType().GetMethod(item.ToString().Replace("\"", ""));

    for (int i = 0; i < Node["story"][item].Count; i++)
    {
        string data = Node["story"][item][i];
        int n;
        bool isNum = int.TryParse(data, out n);

        if (isNum)
        {
            parameters.Add(n);
        }
        else
        {
            parameters.Add(data);
        }
    }

    method.Invoke(sys, parameters.ToArray());

}
```

Comment: I can only mark it as an answer in 2 days, so I'm gonna say it here for now

Answer (score 0):

Your .getmethod call is using an empty string. Therefore your methodinfo object is null. Hence the exception.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zz808e6(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Even after changing it to this
            `var method = sys.GetType().GetMethod(item.ToString());`
It doesn't work... I still get the error, and it's telling me that the error comes from this line
            `method.Invoke(item, parameters.ToArray());`